# Unit.Value from MediatR is returning status code 200 instead of 204

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http-status-codes, mediatr

consider following code

```
public async Task<Unit> Handle(UpdateVendorCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var vendor = await _context.Vendor.FindAsync(request.Id);

        if (vendor is null)
            throw new KeyNotFoundException();

        _mapper.Map(request, vendor);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Unit.Value;
    }
```

I'm getting status code 200 instead of 204 because I can't return `null`. How do I return `null` if my method return type is `Task<Unit>`? Or is there any alternative beside using `Task<Unit>`?

My Controller

```
public class UpdateVendorController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public UpdateVendorController(IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    [HttpPut]
    [Route("vendor")]
    [SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "Vendor" })]
    public async Task<Unit> UpdateVendor([FromBody] UpdateVendorCommand request)
    {
        return await _mediator.Send(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mediatr doesn't return a 200 or 204, it's your controller method that is doing that.  Can you post the controller method that calls _mediatr.Send(...)

Comment: @Neil: Please check my updated post, I understand that MediatR doesn't return 200 or 204, but by default aspnetcore will automaticall return 204 if the return value is null. For POST/PUT/DELETE method, I'd like to return null to be able to get 204. However, Task<Unit> from MediatR won't allow null as return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Mediatr, Unit is equivalent to void, not any kind of object that can be nullable.

I'd suggest you change the controller to be more specific in return types:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateVendor([FromBody] UpdateVendorCommand request)
{
    _ = await _mediator.Send(request); // Don't care about the return type, it's void
    return NoContent();
}
```